# Stone-Weierstrass theorem: Mistakes of the version in Amann/Escher Analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I encountered this problem as I was reading Analysis by Herbert Amann, Joachim Escher (p394 volume Ⅰ of Eng translation of 2nd Ed.).

The statement of this theorem from this book is as follows:

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $A$ a a subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb K)$ containing $1$. If $A$ separates the points of $X$ and is self adjoint, then $A$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb K)$.

where in this book $\mathbb K$ denotes either of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$

---

My Counter Example:

Let $A$ be a subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb R)$ containing $1$, separating the points of $X$ and self adjoint, so $A$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb R)$

*This* $A$ is also a subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb C)$ containing $1$. Besides it separates the points the points of $X$ and is self adjoint, but it is not dense in $C(X,\mathbb C)$. This is because $A$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb R)$, so $\overline A=C(X,\mathbb R)$, while $C(X, \mathbb R)\subset C(X,\mathbb C)$.

I read the proof in this book and find that this part may be invalid:

> Let $A_{\mathbb R}$ be the set of all real valued functions in $A$. Then $A_{\mathbb R}$ is an algebra over the field R. Because $A$ is self adjoint, for each $f \in A$, the functions
> ${\rm Re} f = (f + f)/2$ and ${\rm Im} f = (f − f)/2i$ are in $A_{\mathbb R}$. Hence $A \subseteq A_{\mathbb R} + iA_{\mathbb R}$. Since also $A_{\mathbb R} + iA_{\mathbb R} \subseteq A$, we have shown that $A = A_{\mathbb R} + iA_{\mathbb R}$

It may not be obvious that $A_{\mathbb R} + iA_{\mathbb R} \subseteq A$

Comment: Some of the things you said are unclear, but does this clear up your confusion: when the book says subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb{C})$, they mean a $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra.

Comment: @Aareyan Manzoor Yes, it has cleared my confusion. Thank you very much. I have reformulated my question so as to make it less vague. Besides, I have submit the answer based on my understanding of your comment and you are welcome to edit it if you think it is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C(X,\mathbb R)$ is a $\mathbb R$-algebra, while $C(X,\mathbb C)$ is a $\mathbb C$-algebra. So in your counter-example, the $A$ is not a subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb C)$.

The proof in the book is not invalid. It is a little like the thing mentioned above, since $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb C)$, so for $a\in A$, $(1+i)a\in A$ (Because of $(1+i)\in \mathbb C$).